# Objective-C: multi-parameter method syntax into Swift Package's functions

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, swift-package

**Goal:** to master the ObjC <--> Swift API syntax 
**Problem:** Working with multi-parameter function API.

I haven't been doing ObjC in years and now I need to interface ObjC with Swift packages.

Here's the Swift-Package code:

```
import Foundation

public struct RicStruct {
    public private(set) var text = "Hello, World!"

    public init() {}
    
    public func sayHello() -> String {
        "Hello Ric!"
    }
}

public class RicClass: NSObject {
    @objc public var msg = "Mother has a feeling, I might be too appealing."
    @objc public let text = "Hello Everybody!"
    
    override public init() {}
    
    @objc public func sayHello() {
        print(text)
    }
    
    @objc public func doSomething(msg: String) {
        print("Inside doSomething: \(msg)")
    }
    
    @objc public func doSomething(msg: String, answer: String) {
        print("Inside doSomething with msg: \(msg) and answer: \(answer)")
    }
    
    @objc public func sayHelloTo(whom: String) -> String {
        "Hello \(whom)!"
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble with the multi-parameter syntax. 
Objective-C likes to append 'with' or 'to', etc. to parameter names.  I've learned this via trial & error.

But I'm having trouble with the multi-parameter syntax:

[image]

**Question:** What's the correct syntax for multi-parameter Objective-C method calls?

Comment: Have you tried:
[richClass doSomethingWithMsg: @"hello", andAnswer: @"world"];
or just:
[richClass doSomethingWithMsg: @"hello", answer: @"world"];

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution, adding the appropriate label:

[image]